# Adding Images to an Array in Swift (The easy way)

Tags: xcode

A couple weeks ago I remember seeing a very cool and easy trick to add images to an array. The trick was after you create an array a view pops up next to it and you select the images and they appear in your array. However now I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for.

`var imageArray: [UIImage] = [Image Lateral]`

After you write "Image Lateral" in the brackets the photos menu pops up.